# How to change the status of a Discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to change the status of my Discord bot. I tried the one below, but it didn't work.

```js
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log('Status:Ready');
 client.user.setPresence({
  game: {
   name: 'to radio',
   type: 'LISTENING',
  },
  status: 'online',
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`client.user.setActivity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity). The first parameter in this method is what you want the name of your activity to be.

In the second parameter, you can specify what activity *type* you want in your status (`WATCHING`, `PLAYING`, `STREAMING`, and `LISTENING`). For example:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  // Playing in my support server
  client.user.setActivity("in my support server", { type: "PLAYING" });

  // Streaming <name of stream>
  client.user.setActivity({ type: "STREAMING", url: "<twich url>" });

  // Watching over xx servers
  client.user.setActivity(`over ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, {
    type: "WATCHING",
  });

  // Listening to xxx users
  client.user.setActivity(
    `to ${client.guilds.cache
      .map((guild) => guild.memberCount)
      .reduce((p, c) => p + c)} users`,
    { type: "LISTENING" }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can with this line

```js
client.user.setActivity('your status', {
 type: 'a type like STREAMING',
 url: 'url of streaming',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
´´´
client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity('something',{type: 'PLAYING'});
});
´´´
```

this is probably the easiest way to do it, the types of the presence can be PLAYING, WATCHING and STREAMING, but you can add a url to the last two.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity('something',{type: 'PLAYING'});
});
```

can be PLAYING STREAMING WATCHING